# Request for option to filter which networks appear on Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, filtering, hot-questions

I think most people would agree that the **Hot Network Questions** feature is a very nice one. We can see interesting questions we might have input on, or, more commonly, be exposed to interesting questions from fields we normally have no specialty or interest in. That to me, is the primary benefit of HNQ, and I would say I derive some non-trivial value from it as a feature.

However, recently, I have been wishing we could choose which subs questions might come from. At first it was for reasons that weren't strong enough to be seriously considered for a feature request (seeing Parenting.SE questions that involved child abuse were depressing to me, but the average person is probably less sensitive).

Now, I feel as though I have good reason to make this feature request. Recently, there was a post on SciFi.SE that made it into the Hot Network Questions. It was made on the day of the season finale of *Game of Thrones*, and the question's title itself contained important plot information.

I'm not going to try and clamor for better moderation because that's unreasonable; I'm not going to plead that people make more spoiler-aware thread titles because human behavior will be tomorrow the same as it is today. I just wish there was some way to avoid this kind of situation -- and by the way, this isn't the first time this has happened; it's just the first time that I've actually cared about the content being spoiled -- without having to AdBlock the HNQ as a whole, because overall I love the resource!

**So my request is:** can we choose from a checklist which SE websites make it into HNQ and which don't? (The visible defaults would be the same as they are now.)

Do you think this is reasonable? Would love to hear opinions.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Prevent questions with movie/tv shows/game spoilers from appearing in the hot questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224108/165773)

Comment: @gnat Didn't even realize this wasn't the most umbrella 'meta' site, though now it seems obvious. Is it possible to have this thread moved to meta.SE?

Comment: I've taken to quickly scrolling up whenever I see the icon for one of the sites this happens on in the hot network questions list.  In other words, I find it a real problem as well (especially because you can otherwise find some very interesting questions there).

Comment: @gnat: While spoilers may be the motivation, this suggestion goes far beyond.  For example, I don't ever want to be shown a link to Salesforce SE again.  But some of the question titles sound related valid and interesting topics in real programming languages, so I invariably end up wasting time figuring out that the link is not what I expected/hoped.  Ok, that can happen for in-network questions as well, but specific network sites are trivial to automatically filter, so let's not let the incompleteness of a solution serve as an argument for not doing something easy and effective.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's covered in another MSE request: [Block networks from appearing in the 'Hot Network Questions' list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238100/165773) (FWIW one of the answers in question linked there offers a workaround, a greasemonkey script)

Comment: Did anything come of this? Getting really fed up with seeing Interpersonal Skills questions on my HNQ list

Comment: Duplicate on Meta: [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297)

Answer (score 93):

While I do agree that a lot of the posts under the Hot Network Questions sidebar are not really that interesting to me, I have found a lot of really interesting questions on there that I would not have found otherwise.

The only issue that I have with your feature request is that if the user has to chose which networks they want to see on the sidebar, we will miss out on a lot of topics that we could be interested in.

I would suggest a blacklist of sites that you don't want to see on the Hot Network Questions sidebar. This way if you don't have any interest in parenting questions or television show spoilers then you can just block questions posted on those sites from showing up in your sidebar.

<sub>**Edit:** Here is a depiction of what I mean, shamelessly stolen from the homepage sidebar
**Note:** I have removed some items from the list to limit the height of the image</sub>

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your alteration to the feature request is basically defaulting all SE sites as "checked"?

Comment: Yes, default to what it is now, then you can remove sites you don't want to see

Comment: Kinda like the ignored tags option, but for the the SE sites.

Comment: Exactly, I was actually thinking about that form while writing this

Comment: To clarify: the default could/(should?) be EXACTLY how it is set-up now, because I don't want to change anyone's experience. I just want people to have the option to change it for themselves, if they so desire. Your solution works for me too though.

Answer (score 4):

It's not as good as a proper implementation by SO, but I wrote a userscript to remove all the fantasy and scifi etc. sites from my sidebar. Edit the array of unwanted sites in the source to customise it as you want.

https://openuserjs.org/scripts/stib/stackexchange_hide_annoying_questions/source

Ironically enough, it doesn't seem to work on meta.stackoverflow.com — it looks like the sidebar gets loaded after the script runs, and I can't get it to work.

**Edit** Just found out about [SOX](https://soscripted.github.io/sox/). Someone who knows what they're doing has done this already.