# Film spoilers are showing up as Hot Network Questions

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I've just seen two questions relating to the latest Star Wars film on the Hot Network Questions sidebar on Stack Overflow. I haven't seen the new film yet and I wasn't expecting plot spoilers to appear on a programming questions site.

The questions are from [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and presumably rank high because the new film is a hot topic right now.

The questions were:

> How could Kylo Ren move Luke's lightsaber in The Last Jedi when he couldn't in The Force Awakens?

and

> Why did Kylo Ren believe Rey would turn?

I'm supposed to be seeing the film in the next couple of weeks so should I avoid SO or is there a way to block these?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Prevent questions with movie/tv shows/game spoilers from appearing in the hot questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224108/295232)

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks. I did search for questions on spoilers but couldn't find anything related. I tried to close this as a duplicate but I can't because the question is on a different site. Btw, I have now installed grease monkey and completely hidden this section. The most upvoted answer says that people shouldn't put spoilers in question titles but clearly they do. I see them all the time but these were more significant because the film is still in the cinema and I wanted to see it.

Comment: I spend the majority of my SE time over on SFF nowadays and I'll say we do try to keep our titles spoiler free whilst still conveying some meaning to the question. Obviously there's a grey area in that not everyone will think the same. However, I will say that the two titles you link aren't really spoilerish in my opinion.

Comment: I'd agree with @TheLethalCoder, they don't give away much if anything in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think those are spoilers... they don't really say anything about the plot of the movies. If by "spoiler" you mean "any bit of information regarding a movie", then yes the only way to achieve what you want would be to completely remove any movie-related site from the hot question list.

Comment: Just to clarify a lot of people find spoilers annoying and what constitutes a spoiler is completely subjective, some people only consider major events spoilers and some any small detail. I do believe there should be come built in functionality to hide certain sites from the HNQ. My previous comment was just to note that's what we do as a site, you'll even notice some questions start with "Some random text to avoid spoilers in preview" and we use spoiler markdown. If you do personally have any problems you can ask on our site for an edit. Though you'll then be at risk of more spoilers.

Comment: As a temporary solution, you could use a css editing browser plugin to hide all Hot Network Questions until you see the film.

Comment: @chilemagic as I said in a previous comment I've used the grease monkey plugin to hide the hot network questions. TBH they're just a distraction during work hours anyway so it's not a bad idea.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I can see that some might think these are minor and not even spoilers. OTOH I know people that won't watch the trailers because they're worried about spoilers. I thought they were giving away content in the film and who knows what questions might appear next. It is a subjective thing which is why I think it would be good to give users some control. At least it is possible via a browser plugin.

Comment: Everybody needs to just chill the heck out about so-called "spoilers" in question titles and accept that browsing the internet is going to push information in front of your face. So far the adopted solution results in ridiculously vague titles that are a blot on the network, [where you can't even tell that it's about whatever film you're worried about](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83719/how-did-leia-manage-this-feat#comment141421_83719). In some cases [there's no way to even know what _universe_ the thing is about](https://movies.stackexchange.com/revisions/79647/1).

Comment: Relevant feature request: [Request for option to filter which networks appear on Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297280/4639281)

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think that's a more general problem with Hot Network Questions and tags (if not tags in general) - on many sites tags tell you what the question is about, removing that leaves you with something potentially ambiguous / cryptic that you need to click on to see what it's about (spoilers or not, even if spoilers make it worse).

Comment: Related: ["Possible spoilers" in the title, and what to do about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229614)

Comment: Yet another reason to delete the Hot Network Questions box with Ublock.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Exactly however, we do need to be kind to people who are wary of them and so finding a balance is necessary and sort of a struggle with everyone's varying degrees of what is a spoiler.

Comment: @Glorfindel, what should happens with that cross duplicate? Will this answer get closed and shouldn't have answers or what?

Comment: @Sinatr nothing happens. As the OP notes, it's not possible to close this question as a duplicate. I suspect that if we ever get a built-in feature to disable certain sites/tags from the HNQ, the Stack Exchange developers will post an answer on Meta SE. If they don't post one here as well, somebody will probably copy it over as a community wiki.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm aware that browsing the web risks seeing spoilers. Generally it's possible to avoid such sites but I wouldn't expect movie spoilers on a programming questions site.

Comment: @BenThurley The problem is this isn't just a programming site anymore, it's a network of sites there the only common ground is the SE platform. It makes sense to be able to hide certain sites from the HNQ but at the end of the day doing so will result in even less traffic to these already low traffic sites and works against SE. I understand your frustration on the matter and us other sites try to help people like you out but we can't have titles like "How did this happen to this person?" as that helps nobody.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder and yet one of the questions called out here turned into "why did Kylo Ren think this". SUPER helpful title...... as if it was really a spoiler. People flip out now about spoilers. I even heard someone panic because "KNOWING WHICH CHARACTER IS IN THE MOVIE IS A SPOILER"(yes.... really...). I feel like..... people are pushing it too much. If you want THAT MUCH to be spoiler free.... go see the movie AT release. Simple

Comment: @Patrice This is only my suspicion but I think the title was edited because of this meta post. And I agree that title is not helpful at all.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder ofc it was because of this.... at least it's better than the "why did this character do this action" of last year's GoT questions. THAT was more dangerous than "spoiler" titles. I am a curious dude and I would click on "why did this character do this".... then fall on a spoiler. I prefer an indication of what I'm going to be spoiled if I click on the link...

Comment: Related question on Sci-Fi and Fantasy meta: [Will we ever clean up those ridiculous spoiler-free “The Force Awakens” question titles?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7792/16272)

Comment: @Patrice The title has been changed again, this time to _Why was Kylo Ren mistaken about Rey?_, which IMO is a much better title for the question. Originally, the title was changed after a [comment that I made](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177930/why-was-kylo-ren-mistaken-about-rey#comment479988_177930), where my suggested title had been _Why did Kylo Ren feel the way he did about Rey?_.

Comment: spoilers schmoilers

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton and see, that to me is a fine title. It isn't a spoiler (unless someone believes it's a spoiler that these two characters eventually interact which.... i mean come on), and yet gives me enough indication that if I want the last jedi to be spoilerfree, clicking on this is a bad idea

Answer (score 24):

Hot Network Questions are generated by *something*. To me it acts as inner Stack Exchange advertisement: user may discover another site of network for himself. So there are good reasons to show *hot* (potentially interesting and attractive to wide audience) questions.

However, you are quite right here, the content what is presented has to be actual  to the viewer and there should be a way to control it. What if I hate something (e.g. movie spoilers)? And never want to hear from it again?

Facebook has "I am not interested" option for its advertisement and *probably* uses it to display *less* (or never?) of similar content.

Here we should be able to say "I am not interested in that site anymore" and furthermore never see hot topics from that site. That would limit frustration to only single spoiler and won't defeat the purpose of discovering sites.

Vote [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297281/1997232) if you agree with that idea of blacklisting.

Comment: There are no "good" reasons for hot questions, not in the sense of helping anyone anywhere. If there were such reasons these would be officially advertised by SE management, but this just doesn't happen. The feature is there only to show network wide (primarily Stack Overflow) audience entertaining / interesting questions. If you're interested, refer MSE for more details on that: [What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219922/165773)

Comment: IMO, there should be an option to mark a question as "containing spoilers to currently trending Movies/Series/Games/etc." which either prevents them from appearing in the hot list completely or just adds a "fake tag" to the question title in the list (e.g. _[SPOILER] Why does this character die in Game of Thrones?_ where the actual question title written by the OP would be "Why does this character die in Game of Thrones?")

Answer (score 8):

It's been pointed out that this is a duplicate of a question on a different meta site.

[Prevent questions with movie/tv shows/game spoilers from appearing in the hot questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224108/295232)

I can't close mine as a duplicate because the questions are on different sites. After reading that question and some of the related questions on meta.stackexchange I found a solution using the browser plugin grease monkey to hide the HNQ section. There are numerous other ways of achieving the same thing.

This solution is fine by me and allows others to enjoy the distraction of enticing hot network questions.

**EDIT**
I've tweaked the script so it only hides links to the movies and scifi sites while still showing the HNQ section. This was inspired by MonkeyZeuss' answer.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     HNQ Spoiler hider
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include     *://*stackexchange.com/*
// @include     *://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
$('#hot-network-questions a[href*="movies"]').css("visibility", "hidden");
$('#hot-network-questions a[href*="scifi"]').css("visibility", "hidden");
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's any consolation, you can enable this custom uBlock Origin rule:

```
###hot-network-questions a[href*='https://movies.stackexchange.com/']
```

*Obviously, alter to your needs and add more if needed.*

This particular rule will still show the movies favicon so that you are aware that something was blocked.

[image]

---

**Disclaimer:** I am too lazy to edit this to reflect the SFF site as mentioned in OP's question.

Comment: Sometimes the spoilers are from SFF, so another rule might be needed.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Whoops, must have missed the SFF detail but this still applies, thanks.