# Is meta feature polling effective?

Tags: discussion, meta

Inspired by [Option to hide certain Stack Exchange networks in Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382879/2191572)

I was lead to [Request for option to filter which networks appear on Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297280/2191572)

The [polling answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297281/2191572) has been upvoted by 15% (82 upvotes, 0 down, 518 views) of viewers (or more depending on how long it took the answer to be written after the question).

Is it appropriate to route new questions to this dead-end which has had no activity for over 2.5 years? Should these feature requests receive [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)?

Should it just be taken as an indication that the community (erm, company) doesn't care about this feature? Is anyone important tracking it? Does voting on a poll or creating future polls have any effect on feature implementation? Should average users be discouraged from creating polls?

I am not inquiring to this specific feature's validity but rather whether these lingering things should just be cleaned up.

---

Feature request variations which I've gleaned:

- [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/235923)
- [Film spoilers are showing up as Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361307/film-spoilers-are-showing-up-as-hot-network-questions)
- [Request for option to filter which networks appear on Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297280/2191572)
- [Option to hide certain Stack Exchange networks in Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382879/2191572)

Comment: Considering that your first question was [meta-tag:status-deferred], I'm not sure if I see the actual...issue.  Yes, getting requested features actually adopted on Stack Overflow can be as fast as calving a glacier, but that doesn't mean that they aren't happening.  I think you're more or less looking for transparency on the development cycle and I don't *believe* that they're in a position to really show that off...

Comment: From personal experience on maintaining an issue list: "we have no time/desire/resources to work on X" often also translates to "we have no time/desire/resources to devote time *deciding the status and planning* of X", if X is neither obviously so necessary a thing that the only appropriate time to do it is "right now", nor so obviously a terrible or superfluous thing that rejecting it takes but a few seconds of thought. "Solving" this by auto-rejecting everything older than a threshold is one way, but that has its own obvious drawbacks -- more so than just leaving them in limbo.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, I did see that but I guess this just opens up another (presumably existing) `feature-request` to close sub-meta posts as dupes of a main meta post without jumping through the hoops of migrating it first.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So would you agree that polling questions asked by the average user really have zero punching weight? Even if the polling question I linked got 500 upvotes I assume it would still fall into the "we have no time/desire/resources to devote time deciding the status and planning of X" category. Basically "Yes, that's nice to have but don't hold your breath".

Comment: I mean... why should they have any more than zero punching weight? they're just requests after all, anyone can make them, regardless of how good or bad. There have even been several occasions where a feature was implemented in spite of having a heavily negative reaction. I don't think the scores are all that relevant for feature requests, they simply act as a sorting mechanism as usual.

Comment: @Makoto "requested features actually adopted on Stack Overflow can be as fast as calving a glacier" Hey, Scrat does this several times effectively with an acorn! Don't underestimate the power of a well placed acorn... or twit.

Comment: Related: [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange): [tag:status-declined]

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I can't speak as to the internal proceedings of the SO development team, as I'm not part of it -- but generally speaking, yes, polling doesn't do much unless there's some formal process where polls are explicitly and irrevocably tied to goals. It doesn't mean they're *useless* (gauging opinion can certainly be useful input to the process), but as a wise man once said, "don't be too proud of this democratic process you've constructed -- the ability to put an uptick somewhere is insignificant compared to the power of paying the salaries".

Comment: "Should it just be taken as an indication that the community (erm, company) doesn't care about this feature?" Absolutely yes, the only thing that Stack Overflow the company (or rather, its investors) cares about is making money. Asking for SO to add or fix things that aren't directly linked to revenue is a waste of your time - hence why we got the "New User" indicator in 4 days, and the kneejerk same-day removal of a HNQ for being "unwelcoming" to Twitterati, but many-year-old requests for improvements to core site functionality remain unimplemented.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nope, it's not.

Meta doesn't track feature requests well, as acknowledged by [this answer by Tim Post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317221/369403):

From that answer:

> Meta doesn't track bugs well, it doesn't track feature requests well, it doesn't indicate presence from us well

---

> I think, in 2019, we're going to have to bite the bullet and replace at least bug tracking and feature requests with something else

---

Upvotes can indicate many things: agreement that the problem described in the feature request is real, agreement that the feature request is a good feature, the question/answer is well-researched and useful (still the tooltip on meta for votes), etc.

Similarly, downvotes can mean many things. I can't find them, but I can remember two similar feature requests, one poorly written and one written well, racking up very different upvote/downvote ratios.

Votes are also mostly cast by meta regulars, which means some users (people that haven't registered at the site, new users) are not represented at all or strongly underrepresented.

This means they're only tangentially related to decision making on implementing a feature, where many things need to be weighed, like the impact on the entire site demographic, development and maintenance cost, etc.

---

So, let's be on the lookout for that *something else* Tim mentioned. I hope it will allow us to represent our opinions on requests better, and help us track the status better.

Since it might be an entirely new system, I wouldn't get my hopes up for implementation in 2019, though. If they'd achieve that I'd be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: This answer is perfect and that Main Meta post is a perfect dupe. Now if only there was a way to close my question as a direct cross-site dupe. Maybe I should put in a feature request?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That'd be a dupe ([of this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252287/7296893)) as well. Afaik current consensus is to leave cross-site dupes be and answer them on both sites if it's on-topic on both sites.

Comment: My comment was in jest :)

Comment: "I think, in 2019" so maybe 2029 in other words.

Comment: Maybe [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog) _years_?