# Option to hide certain Stack Exchange networks in Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, feature-request, hot-questions

Is there a way to completely hide the existence of certain network sites, so that questions from those sites don't appear in my "hot network questions" list, for example?

There's a few stacks which I strongly feel shouldn't have ever been created and it bothers me when I see their questions showing up. Which sites bother me and why is not important - I just would like to exclude them from everything I see. "blacklist" them, basically.

I know I can ignore tags, but I couldn't find an option to ignore sites. Does it exist?

Comment: `shouldn't have ever been created` is a really strong opinion. Not that I think you're wrong or anything, just that that goes *a lot* farther than how I'd classify the things I'd block (me, I'd be more like "I don't know enough about Aviation, any time I look at one of their HNQs I learn nothing" or "eeh, I'm not really into Travel").

Comment: @Draco18s There's a lot of stacks I'm not interested in and I just skip their hot questions. But there are a few (3, I think) that I seriously believe don't belong here. But since I don't run the site, it's not my business. I just don't want to see them.

Comment: Yeah. I know what you mean. [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [Woodworking](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/) and [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/)?? Those three really need to go. :P

Comment: Now I'm super curious which are the 3 sites!

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/155739

Comment: More relevant on the global meta site.

Comment: OMG, you are the user of 41 stack exchange communities. Are you OK to see HNQ there? Rather ask your question on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There has been a plea for this on main meta for years. The result: a whole lot of GreaseMonkey scripts that may or may not work, and no official action.

Comment: Oh wait, a better dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297280/2191572

Comment: This is also a feature of [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088), in case you wanted a more graphical way of doing it :)

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE: I find questions from religious sites downright offensive in their stupidity.

Answer (score 26):

You can use user scripts or css style plugins to hide sites in the sidebar you don't like.

Provided you want to block "codereview", you need to inject the following css rules:

```css
#hot-network-questions .favicon.favicon-codereview,
#hot-network-questions .favicon.favicon-codereview + a {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This answer is probably very very useful to web-developers, but it makes every other one sad, especially when such answers get accepted.

Comment: I actually hope the OP is going to accept the other answer here, as that one actually explains information, and this is just a workaround I came up with, since the OP mentioned user scripts

Comment: I actually hope the OP is going to post his own answer and it's somehow possible to use in Tampermonkey (total noob sitting here, who hates HNQ maybe more for inability to say "I am not interested to see questions from this network anymore").

Answer (score 24):

From [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/494004), about the recent version of the HNQ system:

> There are a few things it doesn't do:
>
> 1. Doesn't let you show or hide the HNQ list on different sites or devices.
> 2. Isn't an option for non-logged-in users.
> 3. **Doesn't let you customize which sites you see by either a whitelist or blacklist.**
>
> [...] Solving #3 is likely very complicated to implement so we don't
>   have plans for it for the time being.

(bold emphasis mine)

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. Guess I'll have to see if I can do something with scriptmonkey.

Comment: @Tom: [It's been done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232424/155739)